# Using DisplayFor in foreach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a modal box which has the Title of a Product associated to the button next to the Product when clicked.  The data is coming from a database.

I am currently trying to use an integer, which increments on each record in the table, and use this integer to get the record Title.  However, I have been unsuccessful to print the currently iterated product.

I'm using bootstrap stylesheets.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
     foreach (var item in Products)
      .. display Title, Description, Price, button & modal code 
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_@i"> View Product</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_@i" role="dialog" data backdrop="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">View Product</h4>
     ---> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products.ElementAt(i)) ???? 


          </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="@i">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not just use @item.Name istead of use the Htlm helper?

Comment: @CodeCaster it seems his problem to create @i where i is the index of each row, as mentioned in the answers below, you can define an index=0 (called count in the answer) and increase it by 1 inside the foreach loop and then you can use this variable to mark your div ids with unique value

Comment: @Hadi sure, but that's addressed in the duplicate too. OP doesn't seem to _need_ `i`, but used it as part of their solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you want to number each row? if so, you can do the following

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel>
@{
  var count =0;
}
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.YourField)</th>
   </thead>
  <tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
   <td>@(count++)</td>
   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=> item.YourField)</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

you can apply what you want based on the above example

so you can use count in the following way in your div

```
<div id='@(string.Format("model_{0}",count))'>...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174(v=vs.118).aspx) your Product class might need to be annotated to begin to see the behavior you're expecting.

Have you decorated the Product properties that you want to show up?